# Visual Studio how to determine whether a file without a suffix is a C++ header file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, intellisense

I've written some header files without suffixes (like .hpp or something) for looks nice.

But it seems that Visual Studio only reacts to some of these header files, the others are not shown in the include complement and are not automatically highlighted when opened.

I would like to know how Visual Studio determines that a file without a suffix is a c++ header file in order to hack this mechanism?

[image: include complement]

[image: files]

Comment: By "react" do you mean the autocomplete tries to help? You can #include (almost) anything, including cpp files (which is a terrible idea), so I don't believe the extension, or lack thereof, is causing you problems. Are you sure they are in the <> path? (rather than ""?)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, by "react" I mean auto-completion when including and syntax highlighting when opening files
btw, these files are indeed in my <> include path

Comment: @steve02081504 It seems to be due to recognizing this file named string as a header file. I have submitted it to the developer community. You can follow up [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Visual-Studio-recognizes-files-without-s/10131883?space=62&entry=problem).